# displaying multiple GoogleMap markers on map

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, symfony1

I'm trying to display an array of postcodes onto a google map using PHP and using the Symfony Framework (1.0)

The main problem I am having, is that there is some text associated with each marker, i.e when you click the marker a popup appears.

The main problem is that the text should point to the correct postcode/marker on the map, but for some reason this doesn't seem to be the case:

```
<?php
$addresses = array();
foreach($contents->getResults() as $content):
    $addresses[] = array(
        'postcode'=>sprintf('%s',str_replace(' ','',$content->getPostalCode())),
        'html'=>escape_javascript(get_partial('property/propertyList',array('content'=>$content))),
    );
endforeach;
?>

<?php
echo javascript_tag("
var map;
var localSearch = new GlocalSearch();
var center = false;
var icon = new GIcon();
icon.image = 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png';
icon.shadow = 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png';
icon.iconSize = new GSize(20, 34);
icon.shadowSize = new GSize(37, 34);
icon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(10, 34);
var delay = 100;
var bounds = new GLatLngBounds();

var addresses = ".json_encode($addresses).";

var nextAddress = 0;

function theNext() {
    if (nextAddress < addresses.length) {
        var postcode = addresses[nextAddress].postcode;;
        var html = addresses[nextAddress].html

        setTimeout('getAddress(\"'+postcode+'\",\"'+html+'\",theNext)', delay);
        nextAddress++;
    }
}
function getAddress(search, html, next) {
    usePointFromPostcode(search, html);
    next();
}

var geoCount = 0;
function usePointFromPostcode(address, html, callbackFunction) {
    localSearch.setSearchCompleteCallback(null, 
        function() {
            if (localSearch.results[0])
            {   
                geoCount++;

                var resultLat = localSearch.results[0].lat;
                var resultLng = localSearch.results[0].lng;
                var point = new GLatLng(resultLat,resultLng);

                var marker = new GMarker(point);
                GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
                });
                map.addOverlay(marker);
                bounds.extend(point);

                if(geoCount == addresses.length) {
                    setCenterToBounds();
                }
            }else{
                //console.info('Postcode not found!', address);
            }
        }); 

    localSearch.execute(address + ', UK');
}

function placeMarkerAtPoint(point, html)
{
    var marker = new GMarker(point,icon);
    map.addOverlay(marker);
}

function setCenterToBounds()
{
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
    map.setZoom(map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
    console.info('zoom',map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
}

function mapLoad() {
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map'));

        map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
        theNext();
    }

}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      oldonload();
      func();
    }
  }
}

function addUnLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonunload = window.onunload;
    if (typeof window.onunload != 'function') {
      window.onunload = func;
    } else {
      window.onunload = function() {
        oldonunload();
        func();
      }
    }
}
addLoadEvent(mapLoad);
addUnLoadEvent(GUnload);
")
?>
```

It only happens on some of the markers though. It is like it finds the postcode, puts the marker on, but then displays the wrong details for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that the data coming back from Google, seemed to come back in the wrong order.

Changing the var delay = 100 to var delay = 200 seemed to fix this

Even though it made the map load a little bit slower